# Firefox: only can access websites in private session

Tags: firefox, website

I'm having difficulties trying to access some websites (for example http://uva.onlinejudge.org/) in Firefox and Chrome, it works in IE9, what I find very strange is that I do can access this website in a private window (in Firefox).

Does anybody know how can I fix this? I really don't want to use 3 browsers.

Comment: Private mode disables all set preferences/options/extensions. I would put my money on an extension being the source of the problem. Disable all extensions and check if the problem persists. If it does, then re-enable them. If it does not, then you know that one of the extensions are causing a problem. Disable them one-by-one to find the faulty one.

Comment: I will try this but I don't think it is the problem since I don't use Chrome at all (hence I don't have any extensions) and there I can't access the website either.